# Cannot scp file to an EC2 instance that I can ssh to

Tags: scp, openssh, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instances that were created from the same AMI, which was created from the Amazon Linux AMI.  These are running mysql in a master-slave configuration.  The security group ("db") is configured to allow port 22 from instances running under security group "web".

So, I ssh into one of the web instances, and then ssh or scp to the database instances. This has been working fine for a while.

Today, however, I can no longer scp to one of the instances (the master).  I can ssh into it just fine, and both scp and ssh work fine to the slave instance.

Running scp with -vv produces almost idential output, up to the debug2: line below, which is the last output when connecting to the master.

```
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sending file modes: C0775 77 <filename>
```

Any idea what is going on?  I've tried re-starting the instance, and that didn't make any difference.

Update:

```
/var/log/secure:
  Jan 10 19:02:59 <host> sshd[1987]: Accepted publickey for <user> from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 33285 ssh2
  Jan 10 19:02:59 <host> sshd[1987]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <user> by (uid=0)
```

There were about 20 lines or so added to /var/log/audit/audit.log, all ending in `res=success`

Comment: (1) Double check destination path is correct and writable? (2) The last line is correct, not an error. (3) Check /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/syslog for sshd error/warning.

Comment: I am having a similar problem - I can ssh into my instance just fine; scp authenticates and connects (I see the MOTD) but doesn't transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Changed this:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

To this:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem      sftp    internal-sftp
```

Then restarted the sshd service:

```
$ sudo service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to just run a python SimpleHTTPServer and run wget on other side to download file.

- Add HTTP procotcol to be added in security config for all sources
- run the following command in the directory in which file exists

  `$ sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`
- on the receiving side, run the following command to download file

  `$ wget http://ec2ip.aws.amaxon.com/file.txt`